# React Multiple domains pointing to one App with different Profile names

Tags: reactjs, iis, react-router

We have a react app hosted on IIS. We have the following scenario. A shop registers on this site say with a shop name MyShop. Our website will automatically have a landing page called inshopshape.com/MyShop which works fine. Now we want to have shops to have their own domain say for example MyShop.com. Once they go in this URL they should automatically go to inshopshape.com/MyShop WITHOUT changing the address URL on browser. So someone could go  to [www.myshop.com/products/test](http://www.myshop.com/products/test) and under the hood it should show inshopshape.com/myshop/products/test

Kindly note the following

1. Website is hosted on IIS
2. This is a single page app done with react
3. If the solution provided is one with rewrite rules on IIS then you should keep in mind that react routes should still work when users navigate to the website
4. I can do a forwarding with masking but that's not good for SEO

Comment: You can try using url rewrite. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

Comment: hello samwu. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately rewrite rules did not work in this case because this is a single page app and not served through ASP.NET. Now of course I might be mistaken, so if anyone already did this on a react app he can say that I am wrong :). However I installed Tracing on local, pointed everything on local and did not manage to make it work. IIS is only there as a hosting tool and nothing else. Routes are being handled by React.